# Rails-ShareTribe. Error on npm install (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, ubuntu, sharetribe

I'm very beginner on Ruby and Ruby on Rails and i just managed to install RonR my server. My problem is, when i try to install a platform called [ShareTribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe), although everything went just fine until `bunde install` , npm install came with this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/srv/rails/sharetribe/client/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ postinstall: `cd client && npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ postinstall script 'cd client && npm install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cd client && npm install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/srv/rails/sharetribe/npm-debug.log`
```

What i realized is that My os causes that (Darwin aka. Mac OSX is the valid os)

Is my guess right? If yes, is there any way to install the platform on Ubuntu?
If not, how can i correct this error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install all the requirement within the same version

make sure your npm path is registered, you can use the following

```
export PATH="/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH"
```

now you can install nvm using the following code

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.9/install.sh | bash
```

and write the following to load the NVM and set the required version for sharetribe

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default 7.8.0
```

Hope this would help